# Type checking / define type check

Tags: python, types, ctypes

Forgive me for the poor title, I really can't come up with a proper title.

Here is my problem. Say I was given a list of strings:

```
['2010.01.01',
'1b',
'`abc'
'12:20:33.000']
```

And I want to do a 'type check' so that given the first string it returns type date, second one boolean, third one a symbol, forth one a time... etc. The returned value can be a string or anything since all I want to do is to cast the correct ctypes.

Is there any way to do it?

ps: my python is 2.5

Comment: Sure -- you simply need to decide on a set of rules for what strings map to which "types" and then apply them.  For example, your second one, "1b", doesn't look at all like a bool to me, but my opinion isn't the one that matters.

Comment: What you want to do is rather format checking that type checking. Looks like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: You could roll your own mapping as @DSM suggests, or you could use something like `pyparsing`, or, if you have the flexibility, redefine the interface to accept something like JSON that already has well defined rules and well tested parsers.

Comment: I have [answered something similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10261229/455276) before

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str = ['2010.01.01',
... '1b',
... '`abc'
... '12:20:33.000']
>>> [type(x) for x in str]
[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>]
```

Suppose that you use an eval for determine this list.

Answer (score -1):

If you are completely certain you can trust the content -- that it's not, say, coming from a user who could sneak code into the list somehow -- you could map the list onto **eval**, which will catch native types like numbers.  However there is no simple way to know what those strings should all mean -- for example, if you try to evel '2010.01.01' python will think you're trying to parse a number and then fail because of the extra decimals.

So you could try a two stage strategy: first cast the list to strings vs numbers using eval:

```
def try_cast (input_string):
    try:
        val = eval(input_string)
        val_type = type(val)
        return val, val_type
    except:
        return input_string, type('')

cast_list = map (try_cast, original_list)
```

that would give a list of tuples where the second item is the type and the first is the converted item.  For more specialized things like dates you'd need to use the same strategy on the strings left over after the first pass, using a try/except block to attempt converting them to dates using **time.strptime()**.  You'll need to figure out what time formats to expect and generate a parse expression for each one (you can check the python docs or something like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm)  You'd have to try all the options and see which ones correctly converted -- if one worked, the value is a date; if not, its just a string.

Comment: I'm baffled as to why languages include `eval`. IMHO, it should never be used. If it looks like a good idea, there is a better/safer idea that will solve the problem.

Comment: well, it's free  -- if you've already written all that text to code stuff, people figure 'why not'.  It's probably very useful if you're actually writing the language.