# In a list of strings, how to detect which element could be an other type of object (int, float, date, etc ...)?

Tags: python

When a list of string contains some elements that could be numbers, or dates, or any else element with a type that is not a string, like this list : ...

```
list_of_mixed_elements =[
    "123",
    "3.14",
    "1010-10-01T01:01:01",
    "Say Hello yo' Ahahaha"
]
```

... is there a way to detect which elements could have an other type of object ?

For example, let's try to detect those elements of the list, which could be an int :

```
for e in list_of_mixed_elements:
    test_int = type(e) is int
    print(test_int)
```

Obviously, this returns "false", because each element is writen as a string with "" around (or could also be with '' around).

```
False
False
False
False
```

So how to get a True when the element inside a string of the list (inside the delimiters of the string), matches with the type of object tested ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261141/determine-type-of-value-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: For an individual type check you could also e.g. `try: int(e) except ValueError:` for the types of interest

Comment: anyway to detect that value is a date ?